# Mongoose: How to get latest collection data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose

I am trying to get the latest collection record from my MongoDB using mongoose.

My current code goes as follows:

```
ApiData.findOne(  
    (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
    //            res.status(200).send(err);
        }
        if (data) {  // Search could come back empty, so we should protect against sending nothing back
    //            res.status(200).send(data);
        console.log(data);

        } else {  // In case no kitten was found with the given query
    //            res.status(200).send("No kitten found");
        }
    }, { sort: { _id: -1 }, limit: 1 });
```

But this does not work in sorting the latest data, only shows the first record.

Comment: you want latest added data or all data in sorted order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my problem after searching Stackoverflow.

The problem was fixed by removing `, { sort: { _id: -1 }, limit: 1 });` and adding `.sort.({"_id": -1})` to the end of my closing brackets!

Thanks for trying to answer my problem guys!

Answer (score 2):

To get latest added data :

```
ApiData.findOne({}).sort({date: -1}).exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
    //            res.status(200).send(err);
        }
        if (data) {  // Search could come back empty, so we should protect against sending nothing back
    //            res.status(200).send(data);
        console.log(data);

        } else {  // In case no kitten was found with the given query
    //            res.status(200).send("No kitten found");
        }
});
```

To get all data just replace `findone` with `find`

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! I haven't tried this answer, because I ended up fixing it by adding .sort.({"_id": -1}) to the end of my code.